# How to ad an extra field to joomla 2.5 registration form?

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to add an extra file uploading field to joomla 2.5 registration form for uploading the photos of the users :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1) Modify the file `components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml` and add extra fields to it.

2) Modify function `register($temp)` in `components\com_users\models\registration.php` so you can save path / paths to your file / files.

3) Maybe add additional table in your database or add columns to `#__users` table